# Are the spellings «acção» or «óptimo» correct or not?

Tags: ortografia, acordo-ortográfico

After the orthography reform of 2009, silent consonants are not written any more. But I still see the words like ***acção*** or ***óptimo*** written exactly like that.

Is this incorrect as of 2009 official rules?

Comment: The new orthography has become compulsory in public admnistration, but private citizens and institutions are free to write as they please. E aquelles escriptores e individuos anonymos que tenha preferencia pela orthographia corrente até ao anno de 1911 podem usal-a á sua vontade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, with the 2009 rules this is incorrect. Some public figures (such as writers) refused to adopt the new rules, and this is most probably the reason you still words spelled that way. Other cause maybe that some people (most) still haven't adapted to the new rules.

Comment: I would also like to add that many related words may still maintain their original form, if the consonant is not silent, which may add to the confusion for new Portuguese language students.

One great example is **Egito** (Egypt), and **egípcios** (egyptians).

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not correct. Since the 12th of may 2015, the usage of the new rules, as specified in the "Acordo ortográfico de 1999", became mandatory. There are still people using the older rules, because either they don't know the new ones or they feel more comfortable with the old ones.

Comment: `No, it's not.` So, you answer that it is *not* incorrect? But then you say that the rules are mandatory... these two things seem to contradict each-other.

Comment: @ANeves How so? I'm saying it's not correct

Comment: Oh, I understand now; I read it as a response to `Is this incorrect as of 2009 official rules?`